# How to send x-www-form-urlencoded data using http get method to laravel app by postman

Tags: php, laravel, http

I use postman send x-www-form-urlencoded using http get to laravel app.
My laravel app cannot read input form data. When I change to http post, it work!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can only send data in a GET-Request via Query Parameters
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571284/for-restful-api-can-get-method-use-json-data

Comment: I know what you say, but I want to how to send data using x-www-form-urlencoded type

Comment: Why does it have to be a get request?
While allowed by the specs, it's not recommended
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body